# Heroku, I'm trying to add Google2fa to my heroku Webserver but it responds with a 419 page expired

Tags: php, laravel, heroku, error-handling

I have brought it down from a 500 to a 419 but I am stuck, I have installed imagick through composer but it keeps me from logging in

Comment: do you have csrf_token under the form?

Comment: @DilipHirapara yes I do

Answer (score 0):

I solved it updating my composer, installing Imagick and pushing my composer.json and my composer.lock to github